# Extending jQuery.mobile-1.1.0.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, extend

I would like to extend a core jQuerymobile function. 
Here's the link to JQM library: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js

I want to change line 6574

```
headerClose;
```

into

```
headerClose = $( "<a>", {
            "text": widget.options.closeText,
            "href": "#",
            "class": "ui-btn-left"
}).attr( "data-" + $.mobile.ns + "iconpos", "notext" ).attr( "data-" + $.mobile.ns + "icon", "delete" ).appendTo( header ).buttonMarkup();
```

Instead of changing it directly inside the JQM library, I would like to do it from a custom js file. Im seeking a solution with the least code needed.

Thanks in advance.